Combine electrical service for two formerly separate units of a former duplex
We own a duplex and for a few years lived in one unit and rented out the other. A couple of years ago, we took over the now-former rental and combined the units into one. One complication we still have is that each former unit still has it's own electrical service with its own meter, outside main panel, and inside subpanel (I hope I have those terms correct).
As such, we are paying for two electrical connections. Combining service so that we could have one drop and one meter for the whole building would save us a fair amount of money.
What would be the cheapest way to go about this? In a perfect world, it would be easily reversible so that if we moved, we'd easily have the option of turning it back it a duplex (but that's a "nice to have," not a requirement).
In California, USA, if that makes any difference.

Might not save money.  Will need to compare the saving for one service to the cost of rewiring, maybe even upgrading one service.

Rather than ask random people on the internet, I'd suggest soliciting the input some licensed electricians in your area to offer recommendations.  You'd also need to pull permits for the work, so you would also need to work with your local authorities to make sure what you're doing is legal, especially if they're still considered two separate properties from a legal standpoint.

Can you post photos of the existing main panels and meter box please? Also, who's your electric utility?

A lot of this will depend on what the inspector will allow you to do. If the two main panels on the outside are in good shape, the two feeds to them could be routed to a new meter can by way of a gutter and connected to the load side of the meter with proper lugs. Then a new weatherhead from the meter can to be connected to the power company.
You could also get a meter center with two main disconnects and run the feeds to the sub panels. This would be more expensive but might be required by the inspector.
Making it reversible would leave a mess of unused equipment on the walls

You need to start by

Making a map of the installation, what is fed from where? (in particular are any loads fed directly off the outdoor panels or are all loads fed off the interior panels) what is the rating of the panels? which panels have spare slots.
Doing load calculations to determine how big a service the property needs.
Checking if there are any legal impediments to your proposals (I have no idea what the rules where you live about combining properties are and whether you followed them).

Based on that information you can start to evaluate options such as.

Decommisioning one of the existing main panels and it's associated and transferring it's load to the other.
Decommisioning one of the services and turning it's main panel into a subpanel fed from the remaining main panel.
Upgrading one of the existing main panels and/or it's associated meter base and service, before implementing one of the first two options.
Feeding both existing main panels off a single larger meter base and service.


This should really be a comment but I can't make it so succinct.
First of all make sure your local zoning allows a duplex where you are and you are not grandfathered in. If you are grandfathered, you need to maintain all outward appearances of still having a duplex there.
Second, on my bill, (PSE&GNJ) the fixed monthly electric service fee before usage is $5.  At that rate, to save money on a project like yours is hard to imagine. If all you do is buy a new meter and outside panel and a bit of conduit, and the utility charges you nothing, (service wires to the two existing meters can serve your new meter), and you do all the work yourself, no permit fees, no tools, no painting, nothing else ... .it'll take you 10 to 15 years to break even depending on what interest rates you use in the calculation.
There are better ways to improve your life to the tune of $5 a month.
That's without even touching load planning.  Presumably you are removing a kitchen, maybe upgrading air conditioning,  etc etc ... I don't know .... are you making this your home or did you just sledge a hole in a wall and you crawl through it from time to time?   Sorry, that's a joke, but you get the idea .... you can't JUST BE combining two meters.  You've got to have some bigger goal in mind.     Make a plan, do the math, THEN if you need clarification on certain points, ask questions.
